# alternating computer and player moves in game

Tags: c

In my game, I have a loop which alternates between player and computer. All is good until I reach the part where if a player/computer doesn't have any moves left, it should skip its move and allow opponent to continue. I don't know how to exactly implement this in my current loop.

```
do {
    playerMove(oppositeColor(color), boardgame, size);
    numbermoves++;

    computerMove(color, boardgame, size);
    numbermoves++;

} while (numbermoves < size * size);
```

Comment: `playerMove()` could return 0 if there was no legal move, or 1 if there was a move and you could have `numbermoves += playerMove(...);`.

Comment: What?   If either cannot move, just return early with some 'ImStuft' boolean.

Comment: With two if statements? if(checkIfPlayerCanMove(...)) {playerMove(...); numbermoves++;}

Answer (score 0):

Each player should have their own loop counter variable and you should test for it being greater then zero before calling the move functions.  The loop condition should test both variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two global variable and can use them in two function. For each move you decrements those variable . After for each loop you can check whether player or computer has further moves.